# Do I need an IDP for California, Utah, Arizona, or Nevada?

Tags: usa, driving, driving-licenses, road-trips

I'm travelling through the Western USA — California, Utah, Arizona and Nevada — and have only whole a 'paper' UK driving full driving licence (no photograph). Is this adequate with my passport, or do I need an International Driving Permit?

Answer (score 2):

None of the four states requires an IDP as a foreign visitor. They all require a valid license for your home country, but none stipulate that it must include a photo. Your license plus a passport with photo will be sufficient. If you wish you could still get an IDP from your local authorized affiliate, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your destinations, but on several occasions I managed to rent cars in Florida by producing only a 'paper' UK licence and my passport.

Comment: Thanks, Richard, for the confirmation. That's exactly what I was suggesting - the license should prove a right to drive and the passport will link it to you with a picture (and demonstrate your right to be in the USA). The IDP should be unnecessary, but it also won't hurt if you do wish to get one (the only reason I thought of it was because it will be a 2nd photo ID).

Answer (score 1):

Never had any problems renting and driving a car in the USA using my old pink & green paper UK license and my passport.  I've visited CA, UT, AZ, NV and many other states too.

I've even been stopped by the police for speeding a few times.  I've shown them my license with no problems - received only one ticket and got let off on the other occasions.  Remember though, most US police have probably not seen an old UK license before, so expect lots of frowns and questions.  Being calm and polite, and offering to help by having your passport easily available is a good idea.